# Removing .php extension from the URL

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have found and used this .htaccess code that will rewrite my .php URLs into i.e. .com/privacy/ - even if I remove the trailing slash, it will nicely write it;

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

but when I navigate to site.com/privacy.php it still displays, and doesn't force removal of the extension nor add the trailing slash.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Test this after clearing your browser cache.

Comment: Thank you but your code didn't work on my site. When I went to .com/privacy it rewrote it to .com/privacy/ as I wanted but didn't change .com/privacy.php. Thank you though...

Comment: No you didn't understand. It will change URL to `example.com/privacy/` but will show content of `example.com/privacy.php`. Make sure .php files and .htaccess are directly under `DocumentRoot` and not in a sub-directory.